# Poisson process. Finding 5th and 95th centiles

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I am an undergraduate student of Economics.  Today I was trying to solve 1 exercise related to Poisson process that I found confusing and I would be very grateful for your help, as my Mathematics knowledge is quite basic.

So the exercise is:

**The average number of calls (which follow the Poisson process) per hour is 4,25. 24% of the calls are unpleasant.**

1) What is a probability that in 1 hour will be received exactly 6 normal and 1 unpleasant call?

**2) If call duration is Normally distributed, what is 5th and 95th centile?** (In Normal distribution 95th centile is z=1.96)

---

*MY SOLUTION*:
1)  to find a $\theta^1$ for unpleasant calls and $\theta^2$ for normal calls:

$\theta^1 = 0.24 * 4.25 = 1.02$

$\theta^2= 4.25 - 1.02 = 3.23$

X - average number of Normal calls per hour

Y - average number of Unpleasant calls per hour

$P(X=6, Y=1 | X+Y=7) = \frac{\frac{e^{-3.23} * 3.23^6}{6!} * e^{-1.02} * 1.02}{ \frac{e^{-4.25} * 4.25^7}{7!}} $

Please tell me what do you think because I really feel I am mistaken somewhere and not sure if the Poisson parameter $\theta$ can be splitted in 2 parts.

*Also if somebody could give any idea about 2) question I would be very grateful.*

Comment: The parameter can be split into two parameters $\lambda_1$ (unpleasant) and $\lambda_2$. The probability calculation is not quite right. If random variable $X$ is the number of pleasant, and $Y$ is the number of unpleasant, then you want $\Pr(X=6)\Pr(Y=1)$. Note that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. *No conditioning* on $X+Y=7$.

Comment: Thank you very much! So I need to use conditioning only when 2 events are dependent, for example, if it would be 2 telephones waiting for calls, and we need to find a probability that one receives more than the other. Is that right?

Comment: For the problem you mention in the comment, a natural approach for the calculation would be through conditioning. To be clear on the problem of the post, the *top* of what is currently your answer is the right answer, we do not divide. The answer you give would be the right answer to the problem: **given** there were $7$ calls, what is the probability exactly $1$ is unpleasant. The conditional distribution of unpleasant given total is $n$ is of course binomial, but that's not what is asked for here.

Comment: Maybe you could help me with a second question as well ? I really have no clue how to do it.

Comment: Me neither, since I do not know what the question asks for. Maybe the "centiles" for a single call? Since neither mean nor variance of call length is given, all we can say is that the $95$-th percentile is at $\mu+1.645\sigma$. Note the $1.645$, at $1.96$ we have $2.5\%$ in the right tail. Did the problem really say $1.96$ is the $95$-th percentile of $Z$? Amazing!